# Optimizing arrays loaded into cache

Tags: caching, profiling

I am currently trying to get a better understanding of cache optimization and have read various articles on the subject. I believe I am getting a decent understanding of it, but I need help with clarification of my understanding.

Let's say I have two large arrays that I am going to iterate over. Both are contiguous arrays and I am going to iterate over them in order. Spatially, neither arrays are close to each other in memory. The operation that is performed on the arrays is a for loop that simply adds the value of the index of the second array to the first.

```
int[] someArray; 
int[] someOtherArray; //assume both arrays are initialized with some values and 100 elements 

for(int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
{
    someArray[i] += someOtherArray[i]; 
}
```

In this example when we get someArray[i] we initially get a cache miss, then when we load someOtherArray[i] we get another cache miss, but then am I correct in assuming for the next 8 iterations or so we don't get an L1 cache miss because 64 bytes of the arrays for both should now be loaded into memory?

And in general, is this how the cache will work? Anytime I access some random spot in memory, it is going to get loaded along with whatever the processors cache line size is worth of address space into memory, and as long as I use those same lines frequently and contiguously I will not have to travel to main memory?

For example, say I have a 32KB L1 cache, and I do the operation above. 200 4 byte ints is 600 bytes, so all of them should now be in the L1 cache. If I do another operation with them, this time multiplying the value and assigning it to someOtherArray[i], I will never once have to load values from main memory, assuming I do the operation immediately after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering each question separately:

1. **Yes**. You're correct, this is how the cache works. That's why spatial locality speeds things up (in the context of caches).
2. **Yes.**
3. (Your example) **Depends.** In this case, probably.

If you go through the whole array, it gives some time for the first cache pages to be evicted. If your program were the only one running on the computer, then the answer would be yes, but you have to consider that there are other programs running on the machine at the same time, and the OS scheduler can switch between them whenever it wants.

A possible scenario is that your process gets switched out for another one during execution, that process fills up the cache, then when your process gets control again, the cache could no longer have your data. This is unlikely with the size of the program and array that you're talking about, but just goes to show that you can't make guarantees about the cache as long as there are other programs running on the same computer.

Comment: Also check out this concise explanation of process interruption https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9374